# How can I execute a WHOIS query for all domains registered in a given time period in a given TLD using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, whois

I'm trying to understand how WHOIS works. I know there are third-parties and Gems that abstract this functionality, but I want to have some basic understanding of what goes on. Thus, I'm interested in how to do this in the most direct manner using only standard Ruby libraries and going straight to the direct source. As a test use case, I'd like to be able to pull the 10 most recent .COM domains registered which would give me a model to understand how to query for a list of all the domain names registered in a given time period on a given TLD. It is my understanding that IANA would point me to Verisign for a .COM query, so, if that is correct and I should be querying Versign, what do I ask Verisign and how would I execute this query in Ruby? As well, what documentation or reference could I have used to figure this out myself (I ask because I had trouble finding any). Thanks.

Comment: One step at a time... Firstly, you will need to find a Whois API that you can work with. Searching for "Whois API" is a great start; next you will then need to build a Ruby solution to interact with it (find out what data you need to send/receive to/from the API), then plan accordingly and ask for help at specific stages, if you need it; but at the moment, your question is rather general. It is almost as though you've said "I need this, build it for me".

Comment: Whois APIs are easy to find. I was trying to get some conceptual understanding of what's going on at a lower level and the question was just intended to be a very simple instance of that (i.e., how do I get a list of domain names based on some criteria) to give me some color. Can you suggest a better way to phrase the question and I'll update it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you can't know the last N domains created for a specific .TLD unless the registry authority for that specific TLD provides you access to this information.

And AFAIK, this is a feature that no registry currently provide.

Some registries gives the ability to download a list of all registered domains for a TLD to some authorized partners. This feature is normally very expensive and useful only if you need to know at any time what and how many domains exist for a specific TLD.

Keep in mind this authorization is really expensive and it must be approved by the registry, given that the TLD you want to monitor belongs to a registry that supports this feature.

You cited Verisign. Verisign provides a [TLD ZONE FILE ACCESS PROGRAM](http://verisigninc.com/en_US/products-and-services/domain-name-services/grow-your-domain-name-business/tld-zone-access/index.xhtml), but this is not something you have access for free through their public WHOIS interface.

Comment: Some registries do provide lists of domain names registered the previous day, like .FR currently. Also all gTLDs are mandated by contract to give access to their zonefiles, through a specific ICANN service. This is available for anyone, you just need to respect the contract regarding how you use this data. Note however that a domain can be registered but not delegated, thus will not appear in the zonefiles, and it is completely legit.